# axios-mock-adapter: How to mock a binary response

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, axios, axios-mock-adapter

Quite simular to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740410/how-to-mock-binary-response-in-mirage) I'd like to mock a PNG-Response with axios-mock-adapter.

What I tried yet:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
const fs = require('fs')
new MockAdapter(axios).onGet('dynamic.png').reply(200, fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mock.png'))
```

And another try:

```
// [...]
const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mock.png')
new MockAdapter(axios).onGet('dynamic.png').reply(200, new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64'))
```

Any solution out there?

Comment: try  `Buffer.from(bitmap.toString()).toString('base64')`